# How to return values from HTML form created using PHP MYSQL and AJAX

Tags: php, mysql, list, dynamic

So i have a made a dynamc HTML form that populates list based on data saved in a database.

This is the database format

```
CREATE TABLE `electron_subjects`.`subjects` 
(
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `subject` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `code` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    `semester` INT NOT NULL,
    `year` INT NOT NULL,
    `lab` BOOL NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`) 
);
```

its basically a subject list for each semester now the form is working ok but i want to know how to return the value selected by user for processing..First i have to select the semester based on that the subjects appear..After i press submit i want to get the code,or row id for that subject.As shown in below picture i must get code or ro_id for network theory.

[image: image description here]

i think i need to put the value tag in this line because this is the second list but how to do that ?

```
 echo "<option>";echo $row["subject"];echo "</option>";
```

This is the form

```
<?php
require 'db.php';


?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Selection Form</title>
 </head>

<body>
<form name="selection" action="/display/check.php" method="post"/>

<table>
    <tr>
    <td>Select Semester</td>
    <td>
        <select id=semesterdd onChange="change_semester()">

            <option>
                Select
            </option>
                <?php
                    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM subjects ORDER BY semester ASC") or die($mysqli->error());
                    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))

                    {
                        ?>
                        <option ><?php echo $row["semester"];?></option>

                        <?php
                    }   
                ?>

        </select>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
        Select Subjects:  
    </td>
    <td> 
        <div id="subjectid">
            <select name='listchoice'>
                <option>
                    Select
                </option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </td>

</tr>
</table>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function change_semester()
    {

        var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax2.php?semester="+document.getElementById("semesterdd").value,false);
        xmlhttp.send(null);
        //alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
        document.getElementById("subjectid").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

    }

</script>
</body>
```

This is the ajax2.php file

```
<?php

require 'db.php';

$semester=$_GET["semester"];

if($semester!="")
{   
    $result=$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM subjects WHERE semester=$semester ORDER BY subject ASC") or die($mysqli->error());
    echo "<select>";
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))

    {

        echo "<option value='<?php echo $row['id'] ?>'>";echo $row["subject"];echo "</option>";


    }   
    echo "</select>";
}   
?>
```

This is the check.php file

```
<?php
print_r($_POST); // prints all form field values sent through in the $_POST array

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
echo $_POST['listchoice'];
}

?>
```

Comment: You need to name your <select>'s first

Comment: Ok i can add the button but how to return the final values....where should i put the value tag and how?

Comment: When you submit a form, it pushes your named form elements through to be processed. Generally, say you have a name input put named='name', so you'd type if(isset($_POT['submit'])){ echo $_POST['name']; }

Comment: It's not working because it's sending those variables to check but check doesn't bring them back. Put the code in check.php into the one your form is it, put that code at the top of the screen and change the method of your form to method='<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>' action="post". Then your form variables will show at the top of your screen when you submit the form ON THE FORM page

Comment: its just showing Array()

Comment: hello i think you still havent got what i need..i just need the subject code  or row id for subject to be send fro the form...